# Crowdsourced local consumer prices

Tags: data-request, economics, prices

I cannot find any web resource for crowdsourced consumer prices - e.g. gas/petrol, water, electricity, and food basics like rice.  I am aware of consumer indices such as http://www.fao.org/giews/pricetool/ but its spread for localised ('domestic' category) data (i.e. in towns and cities) is limited, so I'm wondering about crowdsourced data.  Anyone aware of anything?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add more specifics about what you are looking for. For example: what does the requirement that the data be "crowdsourced" mean, exactly?

Comment: Perhaps the FAO reference was misleading. I'm pretty sure what I'm thinking about doesn't exist. There should be something where people anywhere in the world can volunteer info on the general prices they face for basics. Sort of like OpenStreetMap for prices. It could be an amazing resource.

Comment: For food, drug and household consumables you could try www.shoppingscout.com. It's a shopping app that has current local and online pricing.

Comment: i've seen a few separate pieces involving localwiki editathons trying to grow area sharing economies...its a shot in the dark, and mileage will vary per wiki, but you might want to contact them for more info

Comment: Can their database be downloaded under an open license?

Comment: Yes shoppingcount is crowdsource but there is no way to download the data / even less under an open license.

Answer (score 3):

[Gas Buddy](http://gasbuddy.com), the Price of Weed website (SE does not allow a link) and Craigslist all come to mind.

Comment: Thanks. Gas Buddy is useful but only for US/Canada. Unless I'm missing something I don't see how Craigslist can help as (a) it shows ads and not final sale prices and (b) difficulty categorising ads for comparison.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific geography, you should put that in your question. Craigslist apartment listings can be quite detailed and are usually the final price.

Comment: I'd have thought 'world' was rather less _specific geography_ than US/Canada! ;)

Comment: It's still a specific geometry :)

Comment: why does stack block links?

Comment: Can their database be downloaded under an open license?

Answer (score 3):

The World Bank did this kind of project in 2012-2013:

- http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/crowd-sourced-price-collection

> The objective of the pilot was to study the feasibility of
>   crowd-sourced price data collection. Non-professional price collectors
>   used personal computers and mobile phones for collecting data and
>   entering it in a multilingual web microsite developed for the pilot.
>   Price data was collected for thirty tightly specified food commodity
>   items on a monthly basis for approximately six months in eight pilot
>   countries. Non-professional price collectors received compensation in
>   the form of airtime rewards.

The same data at https://app.enigma.io/table/org.worldbank.crowd-sourced.price.collection.csv

Answer (score 0):

## [Numbeo](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/)

Seems like just the resource you are asking for

[image]